# How to redirect logged out users to different page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a website using WordPress. I am new to it. I have a separate homepage for logged out users and logged in users. Page for logged out users tells them to sign up or log in. And homepage for logged in users show them there profile. So the index.php is the homepage for logged out users. And i have created a different page [freevideofy.com/home](http://freevideofy.com/home) for logged in homepage.

I use plugin - login redirect to redirect them to [freevideofy.com/home](http://freevideofy.com/home) when they login in or sign up. And i use plugin - logout redirect to redirect them to [freevideofy.com](http://freevideofy.com) when they logout. But the problem is, if a logged in user closes my website, and again opens it by url - freevideofy.com then they are  not automatically redirected to  [freevideofy.com/home](http://freevideofy.com/home).

So I want if logged in user opens the url - freevideofy.com, then he should be redirected to freevideofy.com/home. I think this function can be used - `is_user_logged_in`

Comment: What is your first page? You have to add a code to that page. did you used any page builder?

Comment: No. I didnt built any page builder. My first page is the index.php

Comment: Wordpress Index.php or its a custom file ?

Comment: I didnt used any page builder

Comment: So its load your theme index.php file, i will post a answer

Comment: @vishal ranjan I have added a plugin suggestion list so that your redirection are made easy without coding. The plugin will take care of all the redirection even if you update the theme like such. The plugin redirection is better while doing in WordPress. Since if you update the theme you need to again add the lines that you added extra into the core files. Make the Work Easy if you have such plugins rather than coding more bro. :)

Comment: @vishalranjan. If the browser is closed the session will be maintained and if they again reopen the browser it will redirect to the pages without logging them into our site itself. If the browser is closed and cleared the browser cache than alone your problem will occur. If the user closes the browser and reopens it again the session will be maintained and you can regain the session from that.

Comment: But i know how to edit. I know basic of WordPress theme development. So what code will i have to add.

Comment: @vishalranjan. Have modified my answer with both the plugin method and functions method. try which you feel comfortable and share thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you didn't used any page builder or set a page as FrontPage ( using settings ), Wordpress should load your theme index.php file as homepage.
So you have to edit wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/index.php file and add these two lines of codes:

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page()) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/home'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where should i place the code, in header or in index.php

Comment: I dont want logged in users to see the the freevideofy.com page which says them to sign up. For logged in users,  there is a separate homepage - freevideofy.com/home.   Login redirect plugins only redirect users when they log in... But when logged in users visit the url freevideofy.com they see the page which tell them to sign up

Answer (score 0):

If you feel a bit more streaky to edit the codes you can use the plugins for redirection also. Since WordPress uses enormous plugins that reduces our work and so i would suggest you to use these plugins for redirection.

**Plugin Name 1: Peter's Login Redirect**

Redirect users to different locations after logging in and logging out.

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/

**Plugin Name 2: Redirection**

Redirection is a WordPress plugin to manage 301 redirections and keep track of 404 errors without requiring knowledge of Apache .htaccess files.

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

**Plugin Name 3: Redirect After Login**

Redirect based on Role here.

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/

Hope so this will be the easiest method to do redirection based on the login roles and login status as such.

If so you need to do it via function in the WordPress you can do it better in this way.

**Function Name: wp_redirect()**

Description: Redirects to another page.

Note: `wp_redirect()` does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in())
{
wp_redirect( home_url('/home') ); // This will redirect to the home page which we have created.
exit;
}
else
{
wp_redirect( home_url() );// this will redirect to the site main home page.
exit; 
}
?>
```

Comment: @vishal ranjan. try placing the `is_user_logged_in()` conditon in the `header.php` file so that it will redirect to the `freevideofy.com/home` if the user is logged in or else it will redirect to the `freevideofy.com/` of the site. Since `header.php` will load first for all the page load actions

Comment: @vishal ranjan. Have you obtained the output as required bro:) If  you need more helps let me know over here and we shall resolve the rest. Or else you shall +1 vote and accept the answer as best one since it might be useful for other developers who face the same issue while development :)

Comment: I dont want logged in users to see the the freevideofy.com page which says them to sign up. For logged in users,  there is a separate homepage - freevideofy.com/home.   Login redirect plugins only redirect users when they log in... But when logged in users visit the url freevideofy.com they see the page which tell them to sign up

Comment: @vishalranjan. Have you set this page `freevideofy.com` as the home page or what in your Wordpress Dashboard under `Settings->Reading Menu`